# Electromagnetic induction in different magnetic materials

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

In my physics high school lecture my teacher taught the concept of electromagnetic induction under diamagnetic materials (though not completely disregarded it in ferromagnetic substance but as a characteristic property of diamagnetic substance)  but the typical high school numericals that are in my textbook consist of conducting ring (as resistance will be low so due to induced emf an induced current is easy to imagine).
So is electromagnetic induction possible in ferromagnetic ,antiferromagnetic substances etc (ie it is a universal phenomenon, independent of magnetic properties of material) or is it dominant (or observable) only in diamagnetic substances (ie depending on the magnetic properties of material)??

Comment: Are you asking if in a ferromagnetic material, e.g., iron and its alloys, there can be induced macroscopic conducting currents? If yes, then see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddy_current. If that is not question, then please clarify what you are asking.

Comment: another aspect of looking into the argument (in case of ferromagnetic materials) might be the strong attraction these particles experience due to external magnetic field (due to alignment of domains and all..) and I suspect that this effect might be much much stronger than that due to electromagnetic induction which has an opposite effect (that it repels the external magnetic field) hence the effect of electromagnetic induction may not be as significant in ferromagnetic materials as in diamagnetic materials, this is the only explanation I can think of, other ideas would be appreciated

Comment: I still do not know what you are talking about but I would like to caution you that speaking of "alignment of domains" due to external field is almost always incorrect. Domains do not change their direction of polarization under external fields of *normal* intensity, instead the domains change their *size* so that the once in or near alignment grow while others shrink.